Laravel AJAX Search Route Returning 404 Not Found Error Despite Correct Route Definition and Controller Method
I have a Laravel application where I'm implementing an AJAX search functionality. However, when I try to perform a search, the AJAX request returns a 404 Not Found error, even though the route is correctly defined and the controller method exists.
Here are the details:
Route Definition: I have defined the search route in my web.php file.
Controller Method: The search method is implemented in my NewsController.
AJAX Request: I'm using jQuery AJAX to send a search query to the server.
Error: Despite correct route definition and controller method, the AJAX request returns a 404 Not Found error.
I've checked the route, controller method, and JavaScript code, but I can't seem to figure out why it's not working. Any insights into resolving this issue would be appreciated.
HTML (Search Input):
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" id="searchInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
</div>


JavaScript (AJAX Request):
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#searchInput').on('keyup', function () {
            var query = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('news.search') }}",
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                    query: query
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#newsTableBody').html(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error("Error occurred during search request:", error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

Controller Method (NewsController.php):
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->get('query');

    $news = News::where('title', 'like', "%$query%")
                ->orWhereHas('creator', function ($q) use ($query) {
                    $q->where('name', 'like', "%$query%");
                })
                ->orWhere('created_at', 'like', "%$query%")
                ->orWhereHas('category', function ($q) use ($query) {
                    $q->where('title', 'like', "%$query%");
                })
                ->orWhereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($query) {
                    $q->where('title', 'like', "%$query%");
                })
                ->get();

    return view('news.search_results', compact('news'));
}

Route Definition (web.php):
Route::get('/news/search', [NewsController::class, 'search'])->name('news.search');


pass csrf_token to the data-field of the AJAX and then clear php artisan cache:clear & php artisan route:clear .Do this and let me inform.

@Subha
$.ajax({
url: "{{ route('news.search') }}",
type: "GET",
data: {
query: query,
_token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
},
success: function (data) {
$('#newsTableBody').html(data);
},
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
console.error("Error occurred during search request:", error);
}
});
same error GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/search?query=r&_token=ezJVuGFPvUazwRhOGcusONWCQ5kFiwyyxWkJhPTs 404 (Not Found)

In controller pass $news as json response. Try it. Upon successful return it will automatically update the newsTableBody.

Have you checked that your project recognizes that route by running php artisan route:list?

@user883992158 yup and the search route is listed
GET|HEAD        news/search ................................................ news.search › NewsController@search
but nothing is changing

this is much more laravel/php question than javascript question
by the way my first advice is run
php artisan optimize

every time you add a new route
and since i cannot see your whole web.php
if you dont have something like this at start:
use App\Http\Controllers\NewsController;

replace your route definition with:
Route::get('/news/search', [App\Http\Controllers\NewsController::class, 'search'])->name('news.search');

if you already did all the above.... the only reason that could bring your app to 404 is because your ajax have an empty GET data or you need the token you could fix both by adding something like this:
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('news.search') }}",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
       _token:"{{ csrf_token() }}",
        query: query
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#newsTableBody').html(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.error("Error occurred during search request:", error);
    }
});

